# Library to sanitize and normalize dirty scraped data

Tags: python, validation, web-scraping, scrapy, data-science

I have a project I'm working on which aggregates data from various websites via scraping and then sanitizes the input data and stores it in mongo.

Currently I have to implement a lot of my own solutions for normalizing or sanitizing dirty/ugly data as it gets scraped. E.g replacing all occurrences of USA, U.S.A, US and United States with just "USA" so that there is uniformity in representation, as well as normalizing currency representations and numerical values. So basically I have to do the following regularly:

- "Fuzzy" match raw string values to normalize representation (U.S.A; US, United States -> USA)
- Parse ranges (datetimes or numerical) from text into a (min,max,) tuple ("1,200 to 1,500"; "50 - 60"; "12+")
- Determine the currency and numerical value from text ($200; £ 1,200;)

My current implementations work but often find cases which I don't cater for in my extensive list of elif statements.
I can't help but feel I am re-inventing the wheel (badly that is), surely there must be a Python library which solves this problem?

Answer (score 1):

- For dates, use [dateparser](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/)
- For prices and currencies, use [price-parser](https://github.com/scrapinghub/price-parser)
- For countries [pycountry](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/) may work
- For numerical ranges there seems to be [pynumparser](https://pypi.org/project/pynumparser/)